# Finding limit of function $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{(1+x)^\frac1x}{e}\right)^\frac1x$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit of function

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{(1+x)^\frac1x}{e}\right)^\frac1x$$

Comment: $y=\frac 1x$ moves the limit to $$\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(\frac{(1+\frac 1y)^y}e\right)^y$$...

Comment: I still get $1^\inf$ form

Comment: @abiessu what do i do after that

Comment: @abiessu 1 isn't the correct answer

Comment: I haven't identified my answer yet, still thinking about it.  So you have the correct answer, could you post that in the question as part of your working knowledge?

Comment: The correct answer is $e^\frac{-1}{2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take logs. The log of your expression is $(\frac1x(\frac1x \log(1+x) -1)).$ Expanding $\log (1+x)$ in a power series at $0,$ get the limit of the log to be $-1/2,$ so the limit in the question is $1/\sqrt{e}.$

Comment: You want to say that the answer is 1

Comment: I don't just want to say it, I did say it.

Comment: But I'm sorry your answer is wrong

Comment: @user2369284, You are right, the corrected answer is posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$(1+x)^{1/x}=e^{\frac 1 x\log(1+x)}=e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+o(x)}$$
hence
$$\left(\frac{(1+x)^\frac1x}{e}\right)^\frac1x=e^{\frac{1}{x}(-\frac{x}{2}+o(x))}\sim e^{-1/2}$$

Answer (score 2):

let $$L= \lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}}{e})^\frac{1}{x}$$
taking $ln$ on both sides
$$ln L= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} ( \frac{1}{x} ln(1+x)-1)$$
now use when $x \to 0$
 $$ln(1+x)\approx x-\frac{x^2}{2}+....$$
the $RHS$ changes to$$\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}+O$$
further removing $ln$.  limit becomes $e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.